# How to display a card on tapping a FAB?

Tags: flutter, dart

So this is what I got so far. Basically, I want to display the card once the user taps on the FAB. Now, when I tap on the FAB, there's no response.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            onPressed: () => logoutUser().then((value) =>
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/SignIn')),
          )
        ],
        title: Text('TODO'),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () => displayCard()),
    );
  }

  Widget displayCard() {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            const ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.album),
              title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
              subtitle: Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're returning a Widget to your onPressed function, which is a `VoidCallBack`. It won't do anything with the Widget it receives back from `displayCard()`.

Consider using a Dialog popup. Replace your widget `displayCard()` with something like the following.

```
void displayCard(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("The Enchanted Nightingale"),
                content: Text("Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein."),
                actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text("Dismiss"),
                        onPressed: () {
                            //remove the dialog popup
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }

                    )
                ]
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Then, update your `floatActionButton` code to pass `context` as a parameter

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () => displayCard(context)),
```